# Angular: ngChecked ngModel checklistModel data binding not working

Tags: angularjs

I am getting problems with using checklistModel with ngChecked
I am using ngChecked to select all input['checkbox'] but value specified in input's checklist-value is not getting updated to array specified in checklist-model

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HCXuEFOsBdPuZ893CtXA?p=preview)

```
<body ng-app="">
  <label>Check me to check both: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="master"></label><br/>
<hr>
<input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="'YES'" ng-false-value="'NO'" ng-checked="master" ng-model="slave1" checklist-model="checked" checklist-value="'slave1'" aria-label="Slave input">
<input  type="checkbox" ng-checked="master" ng-model="slave2" checklist-model="checked" checklist-value="'slave2'" aria-label="Slave input">
<br>
checked: {{checked}}<br>
slave1: {{slave1}}<br>
slave2: {{slave2}}<br>
</body>
```

### Update

[Updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TkB6RdJAl8xfsSdrsmfK?p=preview)
but m y question still remains same
ngChecked not triggering update to ng-model or checklist-model

Comment: what is `checklist-model`? I don't see any directive associated with it inside plunkr

Answer (score 1):

You aren't supposed to use `ng-model` with `checklist-model`.  Here is an example from the [checklist-model docs](http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/):

```
<label ng-repeat="role in roles">
    <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="user.roles" checklist-value="role.id"> {{role.text}}
</label>
```

You use `checklist-model` **in place** of `ng-model`